# Can I use Hyperledger Composer (or Fabric) for file changes tracking and failure detection?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am planning to use Blockchain for following cases:

1. Track changes in the file, present at the peer. If there is some change in the file at one of the peer, then this peer should detect it and also other peers would know this malicious change. Then some another peer on the blockchain network should re-configure (restore) this file on first peer.
2. If one peer fails or basically stop working then some another peer (possibly neighbor) should take or handle the load or responsibilty of the previous peer.

Is it possible to use blockchain for this kind of work?
Can I use Hyperledger Composer (or may be fabric) for application development?

It would be great if you can advice/suggest me on this usecases :)
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a bit awkward, but you could do that. It isn't an intended use case for blockchain, per se. From the description, I suspect that you are looking for the blockchain to automatically detect when the file has changed. That isn't how it works.  However, you could write a chaincode that would check the hash of the file against a hash in the blockchain for discrepancies. However, to restore the file to its correct state, you would likely have to store the (compressed) file in the blockchain and restore that to the file system.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would like to use Blockchain for distributed networks of nodes where each node is handling some sensor data or some kind of load where each node is configured with some specific configuration file. Therefore, if there is some change in this file then there should be some kind of certain parameter transfer for re-configuration by other valid node. I am trying to avoid the use of central entity for configuration management. Also, if node fails then there could be some mechanism to transfer or migrate the load of failed node to other valid node.

Comment: Sounds like you want something at the edge to act as a client to the blockchain network, recording sensor data on the blockchain. That's a pretty common use case. 

As for the second use case, where you want to automatically detect whether and when a file is changed, blockchain is likely not the solution you would apply. You could store your configuration info on the blockchain, and THAT would automatically recover etc.  However, you would need to access that config info via txns against the blockchain, which may be suboptimal.